# Is it mandatory to show my credit card upon my arrival at hotel booked using Booking website?

Tags: bookings, hotels, booking.com

My cousin is going to book a room for me in Istanbul using his Mastercard. I've heard that the hotel may ask me to show the credit card with which the payment was made. If the cost of the hotel is fully payed using the Mastercard, do I still need to show the credit card?

Comment: Do you have an other credit card for your expenses and probable damages in the hotel?

Comment: @Willeke thank you for your help. No I don't have any other card. I will only carry cash with me during the trip.

Comment: It is very likely the hotel will accept an other credit card or you showing the one it was booked on with a letter of explanation of the owner of the card, but not accept you without a credit card nor with a card not on your name without a good explanation why you do not own that card. But as in the other comment, only the hotel can tell, contact them.

Comment: @Willeke thank you. I try to contact the hotel about this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any hotel will almost certainly ask you to swipe (any) credit card upon check-in for security against other bills you may incur in the hotel (restaurant, mini bar etc). Some may take a debit card or even cash, but best to check with the hotel in question if in doubt.

I have not heard of hotels requiring the same credit card as used in the booking to be shown, but again, check with the hotel (or Booking.com) if in doubt.